# Purpose of UrlRouting.axd

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

What is the purpose of "UrlRouting.axd" in web.config?
To get ASP.NET routing to work in IIS integrated mode everybody suggests adding the following line, with absolutely zero explanation as to why it should make routing work:

```
<add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

At first blush this line makes no sense because it just maps "UrlRouting.axd" (that is never invoked from the client) to the forbidden handler (which will always return an error). I don't really like mindlessly copy-pasting things I have no understanding of, so an explanation of how it works will help me. :)